# Create Rice Krispies In Chocolate

Tags: mesh, bump

I'd like to replicate the picture below. I already know how to create the basic chocolate, however I'm unable to wrap my head around creating the rice krispy bumps on the surface. If anybody knows of an easy way to do this without individually making and placing hundreds of little rice krispy bits, that'd be greatly appreciated. Thankyou! :)

[image]

Comment: You could use Sculpt, I'm voting to reopen your question so that I can propose an answer with this method

Comment: @moonboots This is still, in my opinion, a duplicate. Probably better to just add your new answer on the other question.

Comment: Here is the result with sculpt, I doubt it answer the other question which asks for cavity, not bumps? https://zupimages.net/up/20/34/8dar.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a shader. The acitve ingredient is the Noise Texture connected through the height input of a Bump Node.  I added the Diaplacement for added effect, but it is optional (especially in eevee). The rest, I just used as an example of how the whole thing can be made through a shader (not just the crispy bits), should you choose to do so.

[image: Brownie]

With a just a bit more complexity to the graph in the form of removing the Z input vector on the Noise Texture, you can achieve a melted, or cut look on the sides, and another noise texture (clamped with a ColorRamp) adds some more "rice bits" showing through. I also combined the "rice bits" to make a roughness texture so they don't shine like the "chocolate". The more complex you make the graph, the closer to real you can get.

[image: Brownie2]